# What brand of Black PETG filament is *glossy*?

Tags: post-processing, petg

Polymaker Tough PETG Black, although not labelled as "Matte Black", is not as glossy or shiny as PLA Black and I consider it Very Dark Grey/Matte/Satin.

What brand of PETG Black is glossy or shiny and also has high quality (and preferably available on Amazon)? Does a brand specify its "blackness" - glossy/matte/satin?

Should I use XTC-3D resin on Polymaker Tough PETG Black to make it shiny and hide lines & imperfections, but will it still appear Very Dark Grey? What color can I add to XTC-3D to make it blacker?

Comment: Can we reword your question to be something more like "how do I find a glossier black PETG?" or something similar? A "what brand...?" question is likely to be closed as off-topic very fast but I think you have a legitimate "question behind the question" here that can get you useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This question as originally stated is pretty far off-topic: asking for product recommendations. We don't give answers of that form on this site.

However, in general PETG is very glossy unless it's been specifically modified to be matte. If you're getting matte-like outcomes, it might be that your temperature is too low for the material and speed. PETG (at least as it's used as a marketing term) is not a single material but a whole class of materials with different thermal properties, so some brands need to be printed hotter than others. Many materials come out "matte" (and also have layer adhesion and brittleness properties) if the temperature you're using is only borderline for the speed you're printing them at. If you can't go higher temperature on your printer, you could try slowing down and see if that gets a surface more to your liking.

Now, as for specific product recommendations, we can't do that, but I can recommend the Filament Librarian's [FilamentColors site](https://filamentcolors.xyz/library/) as a way to get real photos of a huge library of real materials, which might help you select one with the surface sheen you want.